# Database MySQL race condition

Tags: mysql, race-condition

I am currently building a new object, and I am asking if I have two records to insert at the same time in a database with the same ID and the ID is unique. How will database handle it will it throw exception or undefined behavior will happen?
Could this scenario produced in real projects under a lot of requests from users ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a constraint (ex. Unique Index), one of the transactions will fail.
If you have lot's of transactions, it's given that this will happen at a certain point of time, so you need to handle the failure and generate new id for the failed transaction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Is there a way to ask transaction if failed to be do retry transaction again till it successes? I am assigning id each time incremented by 1 using triggers.

Comment: The database will not retry, the application needs to retry. But if you want "autopilot" solution, you can use a database sequence generator or autoincrement which will assure you never have duplicate, however, in concurrent system with to many users you always need to assume that something will fail and you need to handle the failure from the application.